# How a new version of blackberry application can be uploaded on blackberry app store?

Tags: blackberry

Does blackberry provide versioning of app ?? Like in case of android/I-Phone whenever a new version uploaded, user will get notified to update the app. 
is similar feature available in blackberry ??

also can you clearify how an app uniquely identified on RIM app store . for example android use a unique package name to avoid redundancy .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. blackberry automatically takes versioning of the  application as soon as we upload in app world. Also, the user will notify automatically. nothing to handle from client side. If you wish to provide the update feature on your app. you can always integrate by keeping the control on your web server which will redirect again to the app store.

Any, app that we upload in app world is given with content id which is unique for each app. something like this

https://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/15282

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AppWorld will notify the user when a new version is released.  And I don't think there is any special requirement for unique identification.